# Can a isolation transformer be beneficial when coupled with a lab linear power supply?

Tags: power-supply, noise

Linear power supplies are already low noise, so adding an isolation transformer is pretty redundant but I'm curious, will it make a measurable difference or will the benefit drown out in the already present noise?

Comment: Transformer where? On the input the linear PSs already have transformers. On the output they are DC. What are you trying to achieve anyway, if they "are already low noise"?

Comment: If you mean a line powered liner power supply( aka a bench/lab power supply), it already has a transformer in it.

Comment: Depends on the construction of  the linear supply and the construction of the the isolation transformer is (and how good your measurement is).

Comment: State the problem first before speculating about an answer: Which kind of noise in which kind of setup do you care about? Things look pretty differently for grid harmonics at 100 Hz and for uncorrelated RF noise.

Comment: *Linear power supplies are already low noise* And **isolation transformer** provides **mains isolation** which prevents currents from the mains to flow through a person to earth. An isolation transformer generally **does not** provide (much) noise reduction. Also describe the issue you have with "noise". If you don't know what the problem is, how can you even think in solutions?

Comment: Most likely little improvement. Downside is that depeneding on the isolation transformer, it may or may not connect the mains earth wire between input and output, even if it uses a transformer for the live and neutral. I do not recommend using an isolating transformer unless it is known exactly how it is wired internally and how to use it safely in each scenario. Using it before a lab power supply makes little if no sense.

Comment: Yep you are probably right @Justme.This question was just a food for thought, nothing serious enough to do real research/tests on. Thanks for commenting anyway!

Answer (score 2):

There will be about 100 pF capacitance between primary and secondary of the transformer.

At 60Hz, that is 10Billion ohms / (2 * pi * 60) = 10,000,000,000 / 377 ~~25,000,000 ohms.

Now 25 Megaohms is 40 nanoAmperes per volt.

At 200 volts peak (actually 160, but lets use easy math), the current is 8 microAmps.

That 8 microAmps will explore **ALL** possible paths in finding a path back home.

If you have sensitive circuitry, that constant 60Hz buzzing may bother you.